# How to mark comment as answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, stack-overflow

How do I mark a comment as an answer? The [Stack Overflow Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and meta-overflow FAQ does not appear to cover the topic.

Arrowdodger's comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017335/cmake-force-use-of-non-mt-boost-libraries is the correct answer.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot mark a comment as an accepted answer. There is a deliberate distinction between comments and answers; this is one of them.

Common protocol is to ask the commenter to post an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I've been doing that, but it does not not solve the problem and creates extra work. Perhaps Stack Overflow should provide the functionality since so many members insist on doing it.

Comment: @noloader: The problem is that comments are considered temporary (deletion is permanent), while answers are not (can always be un-deleted).  There's also no comment-to-answer conversion system in place, so the commenter will still have to write an answer manually.

Comment: You could also post the comment as an answer yourself @noloader, and then accept it.

Comment: I'd like to see this added as well.  Yes you can copy a comment and then post that as an answer yourself, however that does not give the commentor the credit

Comment: "Common protocol..." sounds like something ripe for automation.